# Help what type of plant is this?

Tags: identification, indoors

Hi I have had this plant for a while and I am trying to figure out what type of plant this is. If you suspect or know the name please let me know thank you.[image]

Comment: At a glance, it appears to be a [bromeliad](http://bromelia.info/en/about-bromeliad/) of some sort, but that's a pretty large and diverse family. Do you think you could provide some better photos?

Comment: You should've spend a minute more to take the picture. Look at it, it is blurry.

Answer (score 1):

From the shininess and curliness of the leaves it appears to be a soft-leaved type of bromeliad, possibly a Guzmania or Vriesia. There are pups appearing around the base which indicates that the mother plant has already flowered; since bromeliads only flower once and then send out pups as suckers this indicates a mature plant which will not flower again. Best thing at this point would be to separate the pups and bring them on as new plants which will flower in their turn.

Comment: Thank you Colin